# How to make event listener to change a variable inside javascript code?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I set up some event listeners in a traditional way like this:

```
<script>    
window.onload = setup;
function(setup) {
    var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
    myButton.onclick = someFunction;
}
```

What I want `someFunction` to do is to change a certain variable inside my code (when the button is pushed of course). Let's say for example, that I have a function `something()` in my code containing variable `x` and the event listener is active.

```
function something() {
var x;
for (;;) {
    if (x === value set by someFunction) {
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When an event is fired you can do stuff so:

```
   CODE CODE CODE
   ....
    var x = INITIAL_VALUE;
    function someFunc(){
        x = what ever you wish;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to make `x` a global variable.

If you don't want to pollute the global namespace, you use an immediately executing function:

```
(function() {
    var x;
    function someFunc() {
        // May assign x
    }
    function setup() {
        var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
        myButton.onclick = someFunction;
    }
    window.onload = setup;
    function something() {
        // Use x
    }
})();
```

This function creates a local namespace for the `x` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the simplest way would be to define a global variable `var value`, such that it would be accessible by both `someFunction()` and by `something()`.

Another approach, without any listener, could be:

```
function something() {
var x;
for (;;) {
    if (x === someFunction()) {
        break;
        }
    }
}

function someFunction() {
  ...
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  try a 'notifier' decorator
//
function notifier( handler_fn, callback_fn ) {


    // #helpers
    function slc( args, i1, i2 ) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call( args, i1, i2 );
    }
    function prepend( targetArr, arr ) {
        Array.prototype.unshift.apply( targetArr, arr );
        return targetArr;
    }
    function thepush( targetArr, arr ) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply( targetArr, arr );
        return targetArr;
    }



    return ( function( cb, args1 ) {

        var origfn = this;

        return function() {

            var
                args = prepend( slc( arguments ), args1 ),
                out  = origfn.apply( this, args );

            cb.apply( this, thepush( args, [out] ) );

            return out;

        };

    } ).call( handler_fn, callback_fn, slc( arguments, 2 ) );

}



var
    handlerfn = function ( e ) {
                    var
                        T = e.type.toUpperCase();
                    ( this instanceof Node ) && ( this.innerHTML = T );
                    return T;
               },
    F = notifier(
                    handlerfn,
                    function ( f1_in, f1_out ) {

                         var
                            v1 = f1_in;

                         v1.target.innerHTML += ',  coords:[' + v1.clientX + ', ' + v1.clientY +']';

                         console.log( f1_in, ', ', f1_out );
                    }
                );

document.getElementById('btn_01').onclick = F;
//
//
```